# Can you require that a user have a device passcode set for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, encryption, keychain, appstore-approval

A client wants to secure in app in such a way that a device passcode is required to be set before a user can use the iOS app. Does Apple allow this requirement for App Store distribution?

Comment: I sure hope not. That violates the concept that the user is king.

Comment: Here is one scenario: The user needs access to private data on a server and maintain a certain portion of that information on the device. It is a reasonable requirement that the device have a passcode in order to protect this data. The user is not king of everything but does have the choice of not using a particular app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit capabilities based on the user having a passcode.

But then it may be a terrible passcode.

Comment: Do you have experience with an app that passed App Store review with this requirement?

Comment: No but it iseems similar to in-app purchase limited capability apps.